# MutableLiveData ArrayList is empty even after postValue() Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I am now stuck and currently wondering why my mutable arraylist returns null even if it is being updated with postvalue(). I tried to display it using Toast and it displayed [] which I think is null. It had no space in between so it looked like a box. I did toString() it as well in order to show the text. How would I be able to solve this problem?

Here is my Main Activity:

```
val list = ArrayList<String>()
list.add("text1")
list.add("text2")
val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(viewmodel::class.java)
viewmodel.Testlist.postValue(list)
```

ViewModel:

```
class viewmodel: ViewModel() {
    val Testlist: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
    init {
        Testlist.value = arrayListOf()
    }
}
```

Fragment:

Top area:

```
activity?.let {
    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(viewmodel::class.java)
    observeInput(viewmodel)
}
```

Bottom area:

```
private fun observeInput(viewmodel: viewmodel) {
    viewmodel.Testlist.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let {
            Toast.makeText(context, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are sure that the postValue is executed after the observe is set in the Fragment? Otherwise you will receive an empty list result of the initialisation in ViewModel.

Comment: @NelsonAlmendra Yes, it does. I tried it.

Comment: are you sure you use `postvalue()` in correct thread?

Comment: @TechMaxed try to use `viewmodel.Testlist.value = list` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: The way you are getting the ViewModel in the fragment is omitted, so this question cannot be answered with certainty.

Comment: The list is not `null`, it's empty. Empty square brackets are what you get when you print an empty list. Also the `Toast` wouldn't show if the list was `null` as the proper call is executed inside the `?.let { }` block. It seems that you either set the observer after you post the value or post the value into wrong `LiveData` object (in the activity's `ViewModel` which isn't shared with the fragment for example).

Comment: @NelsonAlmendra I tried to use the .value but it still didn't work :(

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Sorry, but I don't get what you mean. Can you please explain what you meant? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You post the value to the `LiveData` object in the activity's `viewmodel`, which isn't the same instance as the fragment's `viewmodel`. Let's take look at the way you instantiate the `viewmodel` in your fragment:

```
activity?.let {
    // activity can be refered by the implicit parameter `it`
    // `this` refers to the current fragment hence it's the owner of the view model
    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(viewmodel::class.java)
    observeInput(viewmodel)
}
```

To get a `viewmodel` that is shared between your activity and fragment you have to pass the activity as its owner:

```
activity?.let { val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(viewmodel::class.java) }
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can see developer guide example to resolve your problem

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#kotlin

// shared viewmodel

```
 class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val usersList: MutableLiveData<List<String>>()

    fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<String>> {
        return usersList
    }

    fun setUsers(users: List<String>) {
        usersList.value = users
    }
 }
```

// Attach ViewModel In Activity onCreate()

```
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]

val list = arrayListOf<String>()
list.add("user1")
list.add("user2")

model.setUsers(list)
```

// Get same ViewModel instance In fragment onCreateView()

```
model = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
} ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

model.getUsers().observe(this, Observer<List<User>>{ users ->
      // update UI
})
```

Comment: @TechMaxed  see my updated answer if this can help you

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but I already found an answer above. Your answer is still a good answer so I upvoted it,

Answer (score 1):

have you used the same instance of your view model? or have you defined another view model in the fragment class? The issue could be that you're accessing a different instance of the view model and not the one were the MutableLiveData was updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
    fun <T : Any?> MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>>.default(initialValue: ArrayList<T>) = apply { setValue(initialValue) }
```

and then use this function as below:

```
    viewmodel.Testlist.default(ArrayList())
```

For me, I have a BaseActivity that other activities extend from it :

```
class UAppCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    protected fun <T : Any?> MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>>.default(initialValue: ArrayList<T>) = apply { setValue(initialValue) }

    protected fun <T> MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>>.addItem(item: T) {
        val updatedItems = this.value as ArrayList
        updatedItems.add(item)
        this.value = updatedItems
    }

    protected fun <T> MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>>.deleteItem(item: T) {
        val updatedItems = this.value as ArrayList
        updatedItems.remove(item)
        this.value = updatedItems
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Where do I put it? Thanks

Comment: You can put in your BaseActivity to use it from every activity but in your case, it can be good to put it in MainActivity and instead of postValue use default method.

Comment: @z95510 I put the fun near the end of the main activity and used the viewmodel.Testlist... on the top. It still didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Look at my answer again, I've added more detail for you

Comment: actually, you shouldn't use viewmodel.Testlist.default(ArrayList()), you have to post your list instead of it viewmodel.Testlist.default(list)

Comment: I just tried it and it still doesn't work. Would you like to delete it or keep it there? Thanks for helping me